# creating controls by threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, controls

Is it possible to create controls by threading similar to this non-working code?

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => Panel p = create_control(param1,param2);
t1.start();
this.Controls.Add(p);
```

The `create_control` class looks similar to:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Location...
p.Size...
p.Name...
return p;
```

Comment: if it's wpf use dispatcher

Comment: The question you should be asking is: "Why am I doing this?".

Comment: Yes, possible but why do you want to do that? In WinForms if you create a control in one thread you cant add it to control created in another thread.(simply it is useless)

Comment: I don't know too much of this argument @wudzik. But if I rememner correctrly it's possible do it using the Invoke delegate no?

Comment: I just have lot of panels, labels, tooltips,... and loading on one thread takes so long. So I would prepare panel in one thread, label on another one and so on. To control cross-thread, I would add each prepared control in form, which I am calling threading from. Also joining threads can help a lot. BTW - Useful comment from Simon....

Comment: All controls on one form must belong to the same thread so creating the controls in different threads is more or less pointless as you would need to synchronize these threads with the UI thread. All you get is the threading overhead and no performance gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking,

firstly you have a class which can create a control with parameters

```
public class CreateControl
{

    public Control Create(string name, Point location, Size size)
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.Name = name;
        p.Location = location;
        p.Size = size;
        p.BackColor = Color.Red;

        return p;
    }
}
```

and then in the winform you can create controls using a thread, and you need to avoid a cross threading operation exception when you add the control to the form by using the invoke method of the form as Tinwor suggested.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void AddToControl(Control control);
    public AddToControl MyAddToControl;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
                                                {
                                                    CreateControl c = new CreateControl();
                                                    Panel p = (Panel)c.Create("panel_1", new Point(10, 10), new Size(100, 100));
                                                    AddControlToControls(this, p);
                                                });
        t1.Start();
    }

    public void AddControlToControls(Control parent, Control control)
    {
        MyAddToControl = new AddToControl(this.AddControl);
        parent.Invoke(this.MyAddToControl, control);
    }

    public void AddControl(Control control)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

so essentially yes it can be done. I am sure the code could be improved to make it a little more concise. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you user1584413. Unfornutely, it did not solve my problem but only because my code is much more complicated, than I posted. Strange is that loading lasts for longer time, than original time was. Anyway, your answer might help someone else looking for similar topic.

Comment: To be honest I do agree with the others about why you would want this in the first place, loading threads whilst speeding things up in some situations can in others be quite expensive as it needs to create the threads and storage for them etc, so I am not surprised that it may slow you down. But whilst I agree with the others you didn't ask should I do this you asked if it can be done. If you have so many controls on a single form, what about trying to separate them into user controls, it might make them more manageable, and only load them as needed, not all on the form load.